# Jquery document ready on dynamically loaded HTML fires early

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am loading a dynamic content as follow:

```
$('#my-div').load('my.html');
```

Inside of my.html is a code like this

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            $(function(){
                alert('should fire later');});
        </script>
    </body>
    <script>
        alert('should fire first!');
    </script>
</html>
```

Originally my.html was loaded inside an iframe and everthing was good.

However in order to refactor and modernize the code it was changed to use ajax load. However, now the order of execution is reversed, because technically the ready event has already fired on the parent page.

The problem with this is that there are dependencies that exist that requires the events to fire off in the correct order. I am also hesitant to move the script block higher up, as this code is overly reused and I have no idea what else would break. Although in smoke testing, moving the script block up works on the one page I was working on.

Is there a to use jquery ajax load and keep the originally intended order of script execution?

Comment: Do you load your html before document.ready? Or is it loaded upon doing some action?

Comment: Antoine I think you got the answer, if I just move out the $.load("my.html") outside the ready event and just inline it, the problem goes away! And I don't need to modify the shared code.

Comment: Glad I could help ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            function later () {
                alert('should fire later');
            }
        </script>
    </body>
    <script>
        alert('should fire first!');
        later();
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you check the load state like this ?

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            jQuery(window).load(function () {
        alert('page is loaded');
    });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

However you can check the state of Ajax load by using this approach :

```
 $( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event,request, settings ) {
$( "#my-div" ).append( "<span>Request Complete.</span>" );
});
```

You can find useful information here : [AjaxComplete()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/)